# Javascript closure scope confusion

Tags: javascript

I am confused with the scoping of closure expression.
I don't understand why output is 40 only.

### js

```
  function multiply(input) {
      var no = 5;
      function multiply2(mul) {
        mul *= input;
        return no * mul;
      }
      return multiply2;
    }
    
    var total = multiply(4);
    var result = total(2);
console.log("result :",result);
```

> **Output**

result :40

Comment: What is the _expected_ value? What exactly is the problem? What exactly don’t you understand?

Comment: I could't find out how the output is 40.

Comment: But you wrote it at the beginning of the question: `2 * 4 = 8` and `8 * 5 = 40`.

Comment: I knew the answer so I assumed that like something like formula  is happening.But I don't know why?

Comment: Because `mul *= input;` and `return no * mul;`. Now you need to look at what the values of `mul`, `input` and `no` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiply(4)` returns a function `multiply2` which has two free variables in scope: `no` which has the value `5`, and `input` which has the value `4`. This line assigns that returned function to `total`:

```
var total = multiply(4);
```

`total(2)` calls that function, passing in `2` for the argument `mul`. The definition of that function is two statements, but it could be simplified to one statement (since `mul` is a local variable and is never used after modifying it, that side-effect can be safely dropped): `return no*mul*input;`. `mul` was passed in, with the value `2`; `no` and `input` are the free variables that were created when `multiply(4)` was called and we know what they are set to, so, in the statement below, result becomes `5*2*4`, which is `40`.

```
var result = total(2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination.It helps me to  understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

The output 40 is correct. Your functions multiply  4*2 = 8 and then you multiply 8*5 = 40. I think if you aren't getting what you expect is because you are multiplying 4*2 and making mul = 8 so what then gets returned is 5*8

Answer (score 0):

This is functional programming called currying. An abstract implementation would be `y = f(m) => g(n) => m*n`. So your input to `f` will be carried into `g` and return a function which is `g(n)`. Then your input to `g` will return the final result.

This can be implemented more than one level. ie. `y = f(m)=>g(n)=>h(p)=>m*n*p`, where the input value will be carried to next function until the final input.

[Here](https://github.com/hemanth/functional-programming-jargon) is some basics of functional programming.
Also a great book [here](https://github.com/MostlyAdequate/mostly-adequate-guide).